# Create does not rollback when validation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Code in the Controller for method (`reservations_controller.rb`):

```
 def create_reserve
        @reservation = Reservation.create(reservation_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          user = User.find_by_email(@reservation.email)
          if !user
            format.html {redirect_to reserve_path(:lpn => @reservation.lpn), notice: 'Customer does not exist'}
          end

          if @reservation.save
            checkout_timer @reservation.expect_start_time, @reservation.id, @reservation.lpn
            @car = Car.find_by_lpn(@reservation.lpn)
            if @car.status == "Available"
              @car.status = "Reserved"
              @car.update_attribute(:status, "Reserved")
            end
            @reservation.update_attribute(:status, "Reserved")
            format.html {redirect_to @car, notice: 'Reservation was successfully made.'}
            #   format.json { render :show_reserve, status: :reserved, location: @reservation }
          else
            format.html {redirect_to reserve_path(:reserve => {:email => @reservation.email, :lpn => @reservation.lpn}), notice: @reservation.errors.full_messages[0]}
          end
        end
      end
```

Code in Model (`reservation.rb`):

```
validate :timeValidation, on: :create
validate :timeValidation, on: :update

def timeValidation
  if expect_start_time < Time.now || expect_start_time > Time.now + 7.days
    errors.add(:expect_start_time, "should be within 7 days from now")
  elsif  expect_return_time < Time.now || expect_return_time <= expect_start_time
    errors.add(:expect_return_time, "should be later than expect start time!")
  elsif expect_return_time - expect_start_time > 10.hours
    errors.add(:expect_return_time, :expect_start_time, "Total rental time should be no more than 10 hours.")
  end
end
```

In the function, when @reservation.save gets executed, the validation function in Reservation model will get called. I expect that when validation fails, Reservation.create(reservation_params) gets rolled back. However, what really happened is like this:

[image]

Before @reservation.save, the create already get committed. But I have `validate :timeValidation, on: :create`. It is supposed to roll back. Why?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you added both :

```
validate :timeValidation, on: :create
validate :timeValidation, on: :update
```

Calling validations multiple times overrides the previous validations, refer https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e0d2207ab321145c117c6d615ce209c6f873605d/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations.rb#L152

If you want to perform validation on both create and update events, just do this :

```
validate :timeValidation
```

Also do `Reservation.new` instead of `Reservation.create`

Answer (score 0):

**why you are creating @reservation using create and again calling save ??????**

Change method like below

```
def create_reserve
  @reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)   // change to new
  ...
  if @reservation.valid? && @reservation.save          // check if its valid?
    ....
  end
end
```

***If issue still exists then try below***

```
validate :timeValidation, on: :create
validate :timeValidation, on: :update
def timeValidation
  ...
  ...
  throw(:abort) if errors.present?        // raise error if error present.  
end
```